# Page doesn't scale properly

Tags: html

I have a page, uf.appload.nu/map.php, that doesn't scale properly. It should always scale so that the page fits the screens width. What's wrong?

Comment: this sounds like "my thing doesn't work, why not?"... this is not really my definition of a good question...

Comment: Your code is wrong.  Without showing us more detail, that's the only answer you can get.

Comment: Please share some code and add some more details

Comment: Hello doctor, I feel bad. Here is my body. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="http://uf.appload.nu/karta16.jpg" alt="MÃ¤sskarta" width="2500">` notice `width="2500"` to make the image fit the screen width use `width="100%"` although there are elements on the page that are hidden ex.

`<div class="monter" style="left: 270px;top:280px;" id="B0210"></div>`

you will need to find a new way how to arrange them since they are likely positioned based on the images size of 2500px and not by the screens size, so you will have some work on those

Comment: Aren't im supposed to be able to use viewport to "scale down" everything depending on the devices width?

Comment: I don't really think you can or what you mean exactly by "viewport" but scaling something with a fixed width (images width set to 2500px) wont re-scale if the device the page is viewed on is smaller or larger

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
img { 
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.monter { display: none; }
```

That's all I can tell you if you don't provide some more info. What are all the class="monter" divs for?